# Polymer and Google Closure Compiler

Tags: polymer, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript

Will Polymer support Google Closure Compiler? What are the reasons why Polymer did not support Google Closure Compiler from the very beginning?

Answer (score 5):

Well I can't answer why there wasn't support for the compiler from the beginning because I don't work on Polymer itself, but I do know that there are people working to make Polymer work better with the compiler now. In the short term, we're looking to add externs like these:

https://github.com/Polymer/paper-checkbox/tree/master/externs

for existing elements and are looking into adding an externs generator so that we don't have to manage these manually. Longer term, we are hoping to have full support for compiling Polymer elements and ensuring that they work well with other compiled code. Would externs address your use case in the short term? Maybe we can try to prioritize certain elements or at least give you some idea of when they'll be done.

Comment: Could be interesting to dig into polymer/polyfills sources to verify if they are compliant with Google Closure Compiler restrictions on JS. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations

Comment: Some more information on using Polymer and the Closure Compiler together, is now available:

https://medium.com/dev-channel/polymer-the-closure-compiler-e80dd249d9d7

https://closuretools.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-polymer-with-closure-compiler-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

A polymer-aware compiler pass looks like it's in the works: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Polymer-Pass